# How do I query Parse to get info from a custom class and display it in textfield in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So, I am admittedly new to Swift and Parse and am stuck. I have a Parse database that has objects in it. I have two classes, the default "_User" class and a custom class called "applicants".  In the "applicants" class there is info to populate a user's profile. When I query the "applicants" class I am getting zero objects back. I'm not sure what the issue is and any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using CocoaPods and have the most recent Parse Framework installed + using Bolts, Parse UI, and MDCSwipeToChoose. Not sure if those would cause some type of error or not.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//Query Applicants 

    var query = PFQuery(className: "applicants")
    query.whereKey("firstName", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

    //Post query in textfield 
         let userFirstName = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("firstName") as! String              

         self.firstName.text = userFirstName 


            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) names.")

            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    print(object.objectId)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }


    }
   }
```

Comment: Is `firstName` in your `applicants` of type string or a pointer to `_User`?

Comment: firstName is a column in my applicants class. I don't have a pointer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the `firstName` column against the `currentUser` object in your query.

If `firstName` is of type string, then you should compare with a string from your `currentUser` object. Something like the following (please excuse any Swift syntax errors):

```
let userFirstName = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("firstName") as! String

var query = PFQuery(className: "applicants")
query.whereKey("firstName", equalTo:userFirstName)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I run it I get, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: What is the name of the first name column in your user class?

Comment: I don't have a first name column in my user class. I put that in a custom class called applicants. In my user class all I have is objectId (first column), username, password, authData, emailVerified, email, createdAt, updatedAt, ACL. In my applicants class, my first column is objectId, firstName, lastName, createdAt, updatedAt, ACL. Also, thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay, that's why your query wasn't returning anything. Do you have a column in applicants which specifies which user object that row belongs to?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Do you mean something like the username that is saved in _User also being included in the applicants class? If so, then no I don't.

Comment: So at the moment there is no column relating the two classes. You could add a column of type pointer to a user in your applicants class. This can be used in your query.

Comment: Also, explain why there is a need to keep the users' details in a separate class instead of the same User class.

Comment: Thanks @kRiZ , there is no reason to keep it in a separate class, but for some reason I can't get my data to save to "_User" class. The way  I have the code written is: 
 var applicant = PFObject(className:”_User”)
       if firstName.text != nil {
        
            applicant["firstName"] = firstName.text
        }
        
        if lastName.text != nil {
            
            applicant["lastName"] = lastName.text
            }
 applicant.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
    
            if success { print(success)} else { print(error)}

Comment: I see. Yes, you won't be able to update a user object unless you're logged in as the same User. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.